# SQL query for selecting sum of multiple column based on other column

Tags: sql

i have in database like this

say a table X with columns A and B

```
X
--
A B
1 300
1 400
1 100
2 200
2 400
```

and i want to write sql query to get result in format

```
P Q
1 800
2 600
```

Where Q is sum of all having same value of A.

I thought of selecting the data in same format and then using the logic display it
is there a way to do with SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT A as P, SUM(B) AS Q
FROM X
GROUP BY A
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select  A as P
,       sum(B) as Q
from    X
group by
        A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A AS P, SUM(B) AS Q
FROM TableA
GROUP BY A
```